# How to resole this npm installation problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I'm a neophyte to React JS and npm. I got a problem here for installing npm. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

```
$ npm install expo-cli --global npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[..................] / fetchMetadata: WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
```

Comment: IMO you could safely ignore this, it's just a warning, not an error. That means that `request` is a transitive dependency of `expo-cli` you trying to install, and that particular version is marked as deprecated. It is something that should be handled by the authors of `expo-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, in fact it's just a valid warning. The author of the request-module (which is a dependency in many other packages and expo-cli as well obviously) decided that there will be no new features or major releases and marked the module as deprecated. It will take some time for other packages to exchange the request module for something else.

If you're interested, here's the github issue where the author discusses the reasons behind it: https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142